# Are there any accurate trigonometric functions in C?

Tags: c, trigonometry

I am working with some programming problems which require the use of trigonometric functions. Unfortunately, the functions in the `math.h` library seem to be inaccurate. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>    
int main() {
  double a, b, c, d;
  a = sin(0.0);
  b = sin(90.0);
  c = cos(0.0);
  d = cos(90.0);
  printf("A = %lf\nB = %lf\nC = %lf\nD = %lf\n", a, b, c, d);
  return (0);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
A = 0.000000
B = 0.893997
C = 1.000000
D = -0.448074
```

So is there any way to make these functions accurate? Or do I have to make my own functions using series?

I googled and so far could not find any way to make the functions accurate but using series.

Comment: Radians.........

Comment: Don't pass degrees to those trigonometric functions. Divide degree by 180 and multiply with pi.

Comment: OHHHHHHH RIGHT!!!!!!!! Now I get it (never was good at trigonometry). Thanks :D :D :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Functions `sin()` and `cos()` expect radians. They are usually “faithful”, that is, they produce results within 1[ULP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) of the mathematical result, at least for arguments up to a couple of thousands.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>    
int main() {
  double a, b, c, d;
  a = sin(0.0);
  b = sin(0.5 * 3.1415926535897932);
  c = cos(0.0);
  d = cos(0.5 * 3.1415926535897932);
  printf("A = %lf\nB = %lf\nC = %lf\nD = %lf\n", a, b, c, d);
  return (0);
}

A = 0.000000
B = 1.000000
C = 1.000000
D = 0.000000
```

**EDITED TO ADD:**

Camilo Martinez points out that “Unit in the Last Place” is a bit of a specialized notion. In simpler terms, there are a finite number of `double` values, denser around zero:

```
++-+-+-+---+---+-------+---------------+-------------------------------+--
```

The exact trigonometric value you are computing almost always falls in-between two of these `double`s (the only exceptions are `sin(0.0) = 0.0` and `cos(0.0) = 1.0`):

```
++-+-+-+---+---+-------+---------------+-------------------------------+--
                       |    ^          |
                     lower  |       upper
                     double |       double
                            |
                   exact (mathematical) result
```

Most libraries provide functions that will, in normal circumstances, give you the `double` immediately above the exact result or immediately below the mathematical result.
This is pretty good considering the difficulty of the question.

Some libraries provide functions that will give you the double **nearest** to the exact result, for all inputs (even `1E21`). This is an astounding result. Until relatively recently this could only be obtained at the cost of expensive computations, but nowadays, you can even obtain this sort of result nearly as fast as with the less accurate functions of the past.

Finally, sometimes you are not even applying `sin()` or `cos()` to the number you would like to, but only to its nearest `double` approximation. This is the case in your example once fixed: you would like to apply `sin()` and `cos()` to π/2, but you can't, because π/2 is not representable as a `double`. You have to apply them to the nearest available `double` instead (this is what the fixed program does).

Such inaccuracies can **compound**. The process by which they do have given floating-point computations a bad reputation, but actually, the way floating-point inaccuracies compound is very predictable and can be taken into account when writing programs that use floating-point.

Comment: Also, of course this is all floating-point with all of the baggage that has when it comes to "being accurate".

Comment: @unwind The implementation of elementary floating-point functions such as `sin()` and `cos()` is a problem that has been very well studied, with very efficient algorithms now available. The mathematical sine or cosine of a rational number other than zero is never a rational number, so any fundamental inaccuracy is a failure of all human systems to represent numbers, and not just IEEE 754.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to work in degrees and have correct results, the standard trigonometric functions are not sufficient. For instance, `cos(90*M_PI/180)` will not yield `0.0`. The error is probably less than 1ulp except when the correct result is zero (or maybe very close to zero), so you might just decide to be happy with using them anyway. To get better results, you'd need to adapt the existing algorithms to work in degrees (in some ways this will be easier since argument-reduction, one of the hardest parts of implementing the trig functions, is trivial in degrees) and do some numerical analysis to ensure you're within the error bounds you want.

A quick fix-up for working in degrees would be to just special-case multiples of 30 (where all the exact results fall) and call `cos(x*M_PI/180)`, etc. for all other values. This won't be perfect but at least it will avoid introducing messy inexactness at points that should be exact.

Comment: crlibm has functions `cospi()` and `sinpi()` (for x↦cos(πx) and x↦sin(πx)) that can be used to build functions that are correctly rounded for small multiples of 45 (but unfortunately not 30).

Comment: Interesting. And unfortunate that it doesn't cover this case.

Comment: probably things like `cospi12` for `x↦cos(πx/12)` might be better for any multiples of 15°

Comment: @phuclv that's a brilliant idea.

Comment: @DonHatch: It is, but why not take it a step further and have `cospi180` for `x↦cos(πx/180)`? :-)

Comment: Uh huh, I see what you did there :-)   I think the idea is that cospi12 is the natural extent of how far there seems to be an actual advantage to the "cospi" kind of function.  Going all the way down to degrees adds an additional factor of 3 that doesn't seem to serve any purpose, as far as I can see.  (There are also additional factors of 2, but I see those as essentially irrelevant either way.)

Comment: @DonHatch: Indeed, but "degrees" are a much more familiar unit than "1/12 of pi", and *no worse* in terms of the advantage offered, so I think they're a better choice.

Comment: I agree that degrees is a fine choice in many ways, among them familiarity to many people, as you point out, but it does have a disadvantage for some use cases, having to do with the gratuitous extra subdivision by a factor of 15 (not 3; I misspoke earlier).  I'm not sure it's necessary to make a blanket statement that one is better than the other.

Comment: @phuclv actually I just realized cospi3 seems sufficient, since cospi12 is implementable exactly in terms of cospi3 (assuming no overflow).