# atan2f vs fmodf vs just plain subtraction

Tags: c, math, floating-point

I have a problem with a piece of code that I wrote to wrap an angle around during an integration and is part of a small simulation that I'm working on. So basically the idea is to prevent the angle from growing large by making sure that it always has a sane value. I have tried three different approaches that I would expect to give the same results. And most of the time they do. But the first two give artifacts around the point where angle value wraps around. When I then generate a waveform from the angle value I get undesirable results because of these precision errors.

So the first approach is like this (limit angle to -8PI +8PI range):

```
self->state.angle = atan2f(sinf(angle / 8), cosf(angle / 8)) * 8;
```

This creates artifact that looks like this:
[image]

Second approach of:

```
self->state.angle = fmodf(angle, (float)(2.f * M_PI * 8))
```

Creates the same result:
[image]

However if I just do it like this:

```
float limit = (8 * 2 * M_PI); 
if(angle > limit) angle -= limit;           
if(angle < 0) angle += limit;               
self->state.angle = a;
```

Then it works as expected without any artifacts:
[image]

So what am I missing here? Why do the other two approaches create precision error? I would expect all of them to generate the same result (I know that ranges of the angle are different but when the angle is passed further into a sin function I would expect the result to be the same).

Edit: small test

```
// g++ -o test test.cc -lm && ./test
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    float a1 = 0;
    float a2 = 0;
    float a3 = 0;
    float dt = 1.f / 7500.f;

    for(float t = -4.f * M_PI; t < (4.f * M_PI); t+=dt){
        a1 += dt;
        a2 += dt;
        a3 += dt;

        float b1 = a1;
        if(b1 > 2.f * M_PI) b1 -= 2.f * M_PI;
        if(b1 < 0.f) b1 += 2.f * M_PI;
        float b2 = atan2f(sinf(a2), cosf(a2));
        float b3 = fmodf(a3, 2 * M_PI);

        float x1 = sinf(b1);
        float x2 = sinf(b2);
        float x3 = sinf(b3);

        if((x1 * x2 * x3) > 1e-9){
            printf("%f: x[%f %f %f],\tx1-x2:%f x1-x3:%f x2-x3:%f]\n", t, x1, x2, x3, (x1 - x2) * 1e9, (x1 - x3) * 1e9, (x2 - x3) * 1e9);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-9.421306: x[0.001565 0.001565 0.001565],       x1-x2:0.000000 x1-x3:0.000000 x2-x3:0.000000]
-9.421172: x[0.001431 0.001431 0.001431],       x1-x2:0.000000 x1-x3:0.000000 x2-x3:0.000000]
-9.421039: x[0.001298 0.001298 0.001298],       x1-x2:0.000000 x1-x3:0.000000 x2-x3:0.000000]
-9.420905: x[0.001165 0.001165 0.001165],       x1-x2:0.000000 x1-x3:0.000000 x2-x3:0.000000]
-9.420772: x[0.001032 0.001032 0.001032],       x1-x2:0.000000 x1-x3:0.000000 x2-x3:0.000000]
-6.275573: x[0.001037 0.001037 0.001037],       x1-x2:0.000000 x1-x3:174.855813 x2-x3:174.855813]
-6.275439: x[0.001171 0.001171 0.001171],       x1-x2:0.000000 x1-x3:174.855813 x2-x3:174.855813]
-6.275306: x[0.001304 0.001304 0.001304],       x1-x2:0.000000 x1-x3:174.855813 x2-x3:174.855813]
-6.275172: x[0.001438 0.001438 0.001438],       x1-x2:0.000000 x1-x3:174.855813 x2-x3:174.855813]
-6.275039: x[0.001571 0.001571 0.001571],       x1-x2:0.000000 x1-x3:174.855813 x2-x3:174.855813]
-6.274905: x[0.001705 0.001705 0.001705],       x1-x2:0.000000 x1-x3:174.855813 x2-x3:174.855813]
-6.274772: x[0.001838 0.001838 0.001838],       x1-x2:0.116415 x1-x3:174.855813 x2-x3:174.739398]
```

Comment: `if(angle > limit) angle -= limit;   ` is not `while(angle > limit) angle -= limit;   ` so basically if `angle = 800000 * M_PI` your last method does not put your value in range. a [mcve] could be useful, with input values, expected, and "unexpected" using `fmod` (forget `atan2f` ATM)

Comment: The screenshot does not appear to be made on a machine that is going to suffer at all when you use *double* instead of *float*.

Comment: The code will run on embedded target with only 32 bit float support.

Comment: No need for while because angle only grows slowly.

Comment: now a [mcve] would _reaaaaally_ be nice

Comment: By subtracting out `M_PI` instead mathematical π, you introduce a small phase error that grows with every additional subtraction of `M_PI`. It is not clear what the exact context of this computation is, but usually it is a red flag when a computation involves evaluating trig functions for large argumentd. Consider representing the angle as a double-`float` to double the precision during accumulation, or check whether use of the `sinpi()` and `cospi()` [functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792939/implementation-of-sinpi-and-cospi-using-standard-c-math-library) may be applicable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more information it's difficult to provide an explanation but I'll try anyway.

The difference between using `fmod` and "plain subtraction" (or addition) like you're doing is that if the value is way out of range already (like `800000 * M_PI` for instance), then the add/subtract method doesn't change the value much (it has little effect) and a very big (in absolute value) angle hits your computation function, without an issue, since no artifact is seen.

Using `fmod` (or `atan2`) guarantees that the value is in the range you defined, which isn't the same thing.

Note that doing:

```
float limit = (8 * 2 * M_PI); 
while(angle > limit) angle -= limit;           
while(angle < 0) angle += limit;               
self->state.angle = a;
```

would be equivalent (roughly) to `fmod` (but would be worse than `fmod` for big values since it introduces floating point accumulation errors because of repeated additions or subtractions).

So if inputting very big values in your computation produces the correct result, then you can wonder if it's wise to normalize your angles instead of leaving that to the math library.

EDIT: the first part of this answer assumed that this super-out-of-bounds case would happen, and further question edits showed that this wasn't the case, so...

The other difference between `fmod` and 2 tests is that there's no guaranteed that the value is the same if already in range when calling `fmod`

For instance if the implementation is like `value - int(value/modulus)*modulus;`, floating point inaccuracy may substract a small value to the original value.

Using `atan2f` combined with `sin` ... also changes the result if already in range.

(and even if the value is slightly out of range, adding/subbing like you're doing doesn't involve dividing/truncating/multiplying)

Since you can adjust the value in the range by just adding or subbing once, using `fmodf` or `atan2f` is overkill in your case, and you can stick to your simple sub/add (adding an `else` would save a test: if you just reajusted a too low value, no need to test to see if the value is too big)

Comment: Yes of course. I'm just trying to figure out why the different result given examples above. The purpose is to just keep the angle from going out into infinity so snapping it in range in one go is not necessary since during each iteration it never moves more than 0.5PI.

Comment: Added a small example. It is apparent that there are small differences in the order of 1e-6 values. It could be that these small changes get amplified and create substantial errors after several matrix multiplications and integrations. I'm still trying to pinpoint exactly what could be causing the problem when using atan2/fmodf..

Comment: ok, I' ve enhanced my answer. Still can't pinpoint the root cause, but tries to explain and justify your design choice.

Answer (score 3):

`float` versus `double` math.

Of course the 3rd method works best. It is using `double` math.

---

Look at `b1, b3`.  `b3` is certainly calculated with `float` precision due to the `fmodf()` call.

Note that `M_PI` is usually a `double`, so `b1 -= 2.f * M_PI;` is likely done with `double` precision math and provides a more accurate answer.  The `f` in `2.f` does not force the product `2.f * M_PI` into `float` - the product  is `double` and so is `-=`.

```
b1 -= 2.f * M_PI;
// same as 
b1 = (float)((double)b1 - (2.f * M_PI));
```

Further: with optimizations and `FLT_EVAL_METHOD > 0`, C is allowed to perform FP code at higher than the precision of the type.  `b1` may calculate at `double`, even though code appears `float`.  With higher precision, and the fact that `M_PI` (a rational number) is not exactly π  (an irrational number), leads to a more accurate `b1` than `fmodf(a3, 2 * M_PI);`

```
float b1 = a1;
if(b1 > 2.f * M_PI) b1 -= 2.f * M_PI;  // double math
if(b1 < 0.f) b1 += 2.f * M_PI;         // double math
float b3 = fmodf(a3, 2 * M_PI);
```

To insure `float` results, use `volatile float b1 = a1;` to do a fair comparison and use `float` constants like `#define M_PIf ((float) M_PI)`

Further. With a fair comparison, better to use `if(b1 < -2.f * M_PIf) b1 += 2.f * M_PIf;`

Recommend OP  print `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` to aid further discussion.

```
#include <float.h>
printf("%d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);
```

---

OP has 2 solutions:

1. Use wider math like `double` for the sensitive radian reduction.

   ```
   float b3 = fmod(a3, 2 * M_PI);  // not fmodf
   ```
2. Do not use radians, but an angle measurement like degrees or [BAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_scaling#Binary_angles) and perform exact range reduction.  Angles will need degrees to radian conversions prior to  trig calls.

   ```
   float b3 = fmodf(a3, 360.0f);  // use fmodf, a3, b3 are in degrees
   ```

---

Note: the `float b2 = atan2f(sinf(a2), cosf(a2));` method is not a reasonable contender.

Comment: With respect to your last point, I had suggested looking into the use of `sinpi()` and `cospi()` in comments, which implies treating the angles as fractions of π, and makes full-circle wrapping exact within a very large range,

Comment: @njuffa Thanks.  `sinpi(), cospi()` are useful, yet unfortunately they are not yet part of the standard C library.

Comment: That's why I posted reasonable C implementations of them in honor of this year's π-day [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792939/implementation-of-sinpi-and-cospi-using-standard-c-math-library).

Comment: @njuffa Your good code relies heavily on `fma()`, yet `fma()` is [not always well implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42166563/2410359) which defeats the value  of these `sinpi(), cospi()` - still good idea.

Comment: I am aware of that, but hardware support for FMA is available on all major architectures now, so my work is always forward looking.

Comment: @njuffa Hardware support may be available, as it is on my machine, yet if the library does not use it, it might as well not exist.  The library implementors simply fell short of a quality implementation for this present day library.  It certainly is not your fault weak `fma()` exists - I am just pointing out weak ones do exist today - even when not expected.

Comment: The thread you pointed to is quite old. I am under the impression *that at this point in time* commonly used libraries that expose `fma()` use the FMA instruction provided by the hardware where it exists (which is almost everywhere now) and otherwise provide good software emulation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157029/discussion-between-chux-and-njuffa).